# ICU Latin-ASCII on Centos

Tags: centos, php

Have ICU 4.2 on Centos 5, but need Latin-ASCII translitarator, which came in ICU 4.6. Is there any easy way to add Latin-ASCII without recompiling ICU (no rpm for Centos) and then PHP?